# Meaning of nan and similar values in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nan, null

I have come across the `nan` value in some of my code and I know how to handle it, but when trying to explain what exactly nan means, I realized I'm not sure myself.  There are also some similar odd values for things that I would like some clarification on.

`inf` this clearly means infinity, but will this show up when you reach the maximum float value?

`nan` what exactly does this mean and when does this value pop up?

`nil` I think I do know this one.  An instance of an object that has not been allocated.  I thought it belongs in this list anyway.

`null` I'm not sure about this one but I think it's similar to nil?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `inf` this clearly means infinity, but will this show up when you reach the maximum float value?

This isn't really part of ObjC, except that `NSNumber` uses this as the `-description` when holding an infinite value.

The actual value inside an `NSNumber` is a `double`, which is defined by C—and, actually, the definition is largely platform-dependent. However, on most platforms, it's an [`IEEE-754 binary64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point). The IEEE 754 standard defines an [affinely extended real number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), with values for positive and negative infinity as well as finite values. It also precisely defines the different ways a finite calculation can overflow to infinity, and how your code can control that. But, as a general rule, yes, if a calculation surpasses the maximum finite value for a `double`, you get positive infinity.

> `nan` what exactly does this mean and when does this value pop up?

This also is mainly about C and IEEE-754, not ObjC (again, except for the `-description` of an `NSNumber`). Wikipedia has a good page on [`NaN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), but, briefly it means "Not a Number", and it's used for cases where there is no sensible value, not even infinity (or where it's ambiguous between too many different values), like `0/0`.

> `nil` I think I do know this one. An instance of an object that has not been allocated. I thought it belongs in this list anyway.

`nil` is not an instance of an object. `nil` is an empty pointer, used when there *is* no instance to point to. It's basically equivalent to `(id)0` or `(NSObject *)0`.

But "an object that has not been allocated" is not an object, and doesn't exist, so… to the extent that it makes any sense to talk about such a thing in the first place, I guess you could say `nil` is the pointer to it.

> `null` I'm not sure about this one but I think it's similar to `nil`?

`+[NSNull null]` values are used as a place-holder object that actually exists, but *represents* nothing, in a place where you can't actually not have anything (e.g., in an `NSArray`).

You may also see `null` if you try to print out an empty pointer as a C string (e.g., `NSLog(@"%s", 0)`). But any code where you see this is not actually legal C or ObjC code.

Also, people often confuse `null` with `NULL`, which means *any* empty pointer.

So, when you have an `id`, `NSObject *`, `NSSomeOtherClass *`, etc., and you don't have anything for it to point to, use `nil`. When you have a pointer to a non-ObjC value, like an `int *`, and you don't have anything for it to point to, use `NULL`. When you want to put an empty pointer into a collection, use `null`.

Answer (score 2):

NaN means “Not a Number”.

Floating-point operations produce NaNs when there is not a number that would be a sensible result. E.g., there is no floating-point number that `sqrt(–1)` could return that would be a good approximation to the square root of –1.

NaNs can be used for a variety of things. Software could initialize floating-point objects to signaling NaNs so that using one without assigning it a value first would cause a trap.

Quiet NaNs can be silently ignored to allow a large computation to complete, with the NaNs to be fixed up or removed later. (Most operations propagate NaNs: If you add a NaN and a number, the result is a NaN.)